# Calling closed source library from LGPL library

Tags: ios, lgpl

I am integrating an LGPL application to my iOS  application. As I am modifying the LGPL application, I am planning to open the modifications I make to the LGPL library.

I am modifying the LGPL library in such a way that, I am integrating a new library to it. So the flow is like this:

Appl Code >> LGPL Library >> **New Library**

Do I need to make the **New Library** opensource? Please note that my questions is specifically related to the call-flow. ie my new library is "used by" the LGPL library. What is the implication of LGPL license in that use case.

Comment: Probably a question for your lawyer, or at least for [OpenSource.SE](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/). IANAL, but my feeling is that you should publish your modified LGPL library source code

Comment: iirc the short version is that the LGPL requires users to be able to replace the LGPL'd library themselves if they so choose. Normally dynamic linking is the simplest way to do that, but (according to the FSF's FAQ) static linking is okay *iff* you provide all of the static object files an end user would need to relink your program. How any of this works on iOS where the users can't do any recompiling or relinking of their own I'm not entirely sure. Also, some projects use "LGPL with a special iOS exception" because of this dilemma, so check if the library is really LGPL or not.

Answer (score 3):

LGPL and iOS applications [don't mix well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501685/ios-app-and-lgpl-issue). For iPhone apps have to be statically linked together so everything must at the very least be LGPL. You cannot have parts be closed source.